# Prove that there is no polynomial $P(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 $

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, contest-math

From Putnam and Beyond.
My question is, how does this proof work? I'd like to know more about the intuition behind its mechanics.

Prove that there is no polynomial $P(x) = a_n x^n +  a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots  + a_0 $, with integer coefficients and of degree at least 1 with the property that $P(0), P(1), P(2), \ldots ,$  are all prime numbers.

Solution:

> Assume the contrary. 
> Let $P(0) = p$ with $p$ prime.
> Then $a_0 = p$.
>  And $P(kp)$ is divisible by $p$ for all $k \geq 1$.
> Because we assumed that all these numbers are prime, it follows that $P(kp) = p$ for $k \geq 1$.
> Therefore, $P(x)$ takes the same value infinitely many times, a contradiction.
> Hence the conclusion.

Comment: I'll edit my post for better clarity

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  I think proofs by contradiction are counterintuitive by nature.  And it's a pretty contrived problem to start with.

Comment: What part of the proof is giving you trouble? Are you having trouble understanding it or are you asking how one might think to produce the proof?

Comment: @mathematician: why it is "pretty contrived" to ask the very natural question: can there be a polynomial function on the integers whose values are al prime?

Comment: The question is especially not "contrived" since there were many attempts to produce prime numbers with polynomials. For example, famous Euler's $P(n)=n^2 +n+41$ which gives prime numbers for naturals less than 40.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that since $a_0=p$ we have that

$$P(kp)=a_nk^n\cdot p^n+a_{n-1}k^{n-1}\cdot p^{n-1}+\dots + p$$

In other words, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(kp)$ is a (finite) sum of multiples of $p$ (notice the powers of $p$ on each term). Hence, $P(kp)$ is divisible by $p$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

However, by hypothesis $P(kp)$ is prime for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (because $kp \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$).

In other words, we have that, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(kp)$ is a prime that is divisible by $p$ (which is itself a prime). This means $P(kp)=p$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so $P$ takes the same value (the value $p$) infinitely many times.

Do you understand why this last bit (taking a value infinitely many times, for a polynomial) is a contradiction?

Comment: `this last bit (taking a value infinitely many times, for a polynomial) is a contradiction` It's not a contradiction unless you add (and use) the assumption that $P$ is of degree $\ge 1$.

Comment: @dxiv: the question says the polynomial has degree at least 1.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, but the answer as written does not make the point that that's an essential assumption. Given that the OP is asking for clarification of a given proof, I think it's important to carefully emphasize *all* the relevant points.

Comment: I disagree. The answer above explains the key algebraic trick and asks the OP whether he or she needs more help to complete the proof. That's good pedagogy in my opinion.

Comment: @RobArthan We'll have to agree to disagree then. The part that's highlighted in my first comment is false as textually written, and may further confuse rather than help a poster who is admittedly fuzzy on *some* part of the proof. Of course, that's just my opinion, which everybody is free to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative proof provided by Hardy in his book
["An Introduction To The Theory Of Numbers"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/An-Introduction-Theory-Numbers-Hardy/dp/0199219869), Theorem 21, page 18
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the last part confuses you, you can proceed as follows:

Let $Q(x)=P(x)-p$.

Notice that $Q$ has the same degree as $P$ (say, $n$). Then $Q(x)=0$ infinitely many times, but this is a contradiction since $n$ is finite.