# Show that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $43 \mid(n^2+n+41)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Show that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $43 \mid(n^2+n+41)$.

Assume $f(n) = (n^2+n+41)$. Then $f(1)=1^2+1+41 = 43$.  So $f(1) \equiv 0 \pmod{43}$.  If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$ then $f(n)=0 \pmod{43}$.

Is this proof correct?  I'm just starting to learn some number theory and I'm not as confident in this as, say, real analysis or linear algebra.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This shows that there are infinitely many $n$ where $43\mid n^2+n+41$, but doesn't immediately say anything about $42$.

Comment: typo...fixing it.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct. Note that for any $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $a \neq b \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $a-b | f(a) - f(b)$, and setting $a = 43k+1, b = 1$ yields the conclusion :)

Comment: Looks good.  Also note that $n^2+n+41\equiv n^2+n-2\pmod{43}$.  $n^2+n-2=(n+2)(n-1)$, so $n=43k-2$ should be a solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks correct. **Just for the record**, this technique is covered in Hardy's  "An Introduction To The Theory Of Numbers" (more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922009/prove-that-there-is-no-polynomial-px-a-n-xn-a-n-1-xn-1-ldots-a/1922064#1922064)), if $f(x)$ is a polynomial then:
$$f(k)=m \Rightarrow m \mid f(m\cdot n + k), \forall n$$

Comment: Off topic, but, Is Hardy's book really good?  i.e. would you recommend it to someone at, say, the advanced undergrad level?

Comment: @IdleMathGuy it was updated several times, I personally like it. Check the pdf version ... Or content/index with Amazon preview.