# Contradiction problem from $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots+ a_0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Prove that there is no polynomial $$P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots+ a_0$$ with integer coefficients and of degree at least $1$ with the property that $P(0), P(1), P(2), \dots$ are all prime numbers.

How should one approach this? Contradiction seems plausible if we would assume it we would get that $P(0), P(1), P(2) \dots$ would all equal some primes. Also from $P(0) = q$, where $q$ is some prime we would get that $a_0=q.$ From here on I don’t quite know how to continue... Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $P(a_0)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that there is no polynomial $P(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922009/prove-that-there-is-no-polynomial-px-a-n-xn-a-n-1-xn-1-ldots-a)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of lack of pure prime producing polynomials.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304330/proof-of-lack-of-pure-prime-producing-polynomials)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is that $a-b|P(a)-P(b)$ (if you haven’t seen this already you should try proving it, it’s a nice exercise).

From here, if $P(n) = p$, then $p$ divides $P(n+kp)$ for all positive $k$. But since all of these are prime, we get that $P(n+kp)=p$, and so $P$ takes the same value infinitely many times, and hence is constant, contradicting the degree condition.

Comment: Hmm I don’t think I follow with the first result. Isn’t $P(a)-P(b) = p - q$ for some primes $p, q$? If so, how do we get the result that $a-b | p-q$?

Comment: It suffices to show that $a-b|a^n-b^n$, since $P$ is a sum of powers. But $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+b^{n-1})$, as required.

Comment: Just to clarify, the statement $a-b \vert P(a) - P(b)$ holds for any polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients. Not just the one in the question.