# Proof For Prime Polynomials

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I've recently encountered this question:
\begin{align}
& \text{Prove that there is no positive integer $k$ such} \\ & \text{that } \forall x\in \text{ positive integers, } x^2+5x+k\text{ is prime}.
\end{align}
After playing around with it for a while, I decided to use the quadratic formula to solve and found some intricacies, namely, the discriminant (where $k$ is located) can only have values where $k < 6$; any value greater than that will not yield a real solution.

As it turns out, only $k = 4$ has an integer solution to $x$ and it is a negative number. At this point, I'm quite lost as to how this would be utilized to prove the statement and whether this would be a valid proof. Any ideas?

Thank you

Brandon

Comment: Take $x=k$ (for $k>1$).

Comment: @Äres Certainly you mean "for $k=1$, take $x=2$"

Comment: @player3236  $15$ is not prime, for $x=k=1$ we have $7$.

Comment: I suggest proving a stronger statement:  there is no non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients  that returns only primes for natural number arguments.  If the constant term is $\neq \pm 1$ this is obvious (since $k\,|\,f(nk)$ for any integer $n$).  It's a little harder to cover the cases where the constant term is $\pm 1$ but you can dodge that in your case (just handle $k=1$ separately).

Comment: @Äres We want "not prime".

Comment: @player3236 $x^2+5x+k$ **is** prime.

Comment: @Äres $\neg \exists k \forall x (x^2+5x+k \text{ prime}) \equiv \forall k \exists x \neg( x^2+5x+k \text{ prime})$

Comment: It seems from the comments that there is some confusion as regards the question.  I think it is clear that it means:  "show that, for all $k\in \mathbb N$, there exists some $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $f(n)$ is not prime."

Comment: But what is with discriminant? We are not solving for roots of the equation. $x$ is already a positive integer and so is $k$. The equation will never get to zero.

Comment: @lulu  note the original problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357  which happens if we just take $x=t-2$ and replca $k$ by $k-6$

Comment: @lulu Regarding the stronger result, I'm pretty sure I've seen it somewhere before (especially the case $k=\pm1$) Where can I find the result? It seems that it is due to Goldbach/Legendre.

Comment: @player3236 it suffices to say that the values are eventually larger than $1;$ and strictly increasing. if we have $f(n_1) = p$ is prime, then $f(n_1 + p) $   is divisble by $p$ therefore composite

Comment: This is true for [any polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922009/prove-that-there-is-no-polynomial-px-a-n-xn-a-n-1-xn-1-ldots-a/1922064#1922064).

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x^2+5x+k=(x-1)(x+6)+(k+6)$$

Taking $x=(k+6)n+1$ for any $n$, we have $x-1=(k+6)n$, in which case

$$x^2+5x+k=(k+6)(n(x+6)+1)$$

which is a factorization of $x^2+5x+k$, with each factor greater than $1$ if $n\gt0$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f(x+1)-f(x)=2x+6$, in other words it is strictly even.

First, we suppose that $k=2j$ i.e. even. Then, immediately we have $f(1)=2j+6$ (since $f(0)=2j$) which is composite and hence contradicts the original claim.

Now suppose $k=2j+1$ i.e. odd. Then, $f(1)=2j+7, f(2)=2j+15, f(3)=2j+25$.

See if you can spot why one of these must be a multiple of $3$. Once you've shown this, it contradicts the claim for all odd $k$ that $f(x)$ is prime $\forall x$, and so combining the two parts you have a proof that there is no such $k\in \Bbb N$

Comment: mistake found, correcting