# Finding non-primes for $n^2+n+17$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If I'm given $n^2+n+17$ and I'm asked to find some $n\in \mathbb N$ such that the polynomial is not prime, is there any reasoning I can use to quickly find a counter-example?

It took a good minute for me to guess one counter-example, $n=17$. But is there a way I could have found a counter example without some lucky trial-and-error?

Comment: if it appears in every summand, then you can **factor it**

Comment: $n=17k, \forall k \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: $n=17k-1$ are examples too

Comment: In fact, $n^2+n+17$ is prime for $0\leq n\leq15$. It fails at $n=16$, as modulo $17$ we have $$16^2+16+17\equiv(-1)^2+(-1)+0\equiv0\pmod{17}.$$

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type) is somewhat related

Comment: An (more or less) universal answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922009/prove-that-there-is-no-polynomial-px-a-n-xn-a-n-1-xn-1-ldots-a/1922064#1922064).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n=17$ is a good choice, because if $17$ divides $n$, then $17$ divides $n^2$ and $n^2+n+17$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on slightly to J. W. Tanner's excellent answer, if we have the quadratic
$$ax^2+bx+c$$
then a value for $x$ that makes this composite (non-prime) will be the lowest common multiple of $a,b,c$ (assuming all the coefficents aren't $1$).

If any of the coefficients are negative, then I suppose you'd need to check if this input is indeed positive.